# Command execution in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, ssh, skype

My server is running on OS `ubuntu 10.4`.

When I run command `"skype -callto userid"` it makes a call using Skype user interface.

But when I run same command by connecting via SSH or

java code

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)`, its not working.

**What could be the reason of such behavior?**

Comment: How do the command to run Skype and `java code` relate?

Comment: cadams.. for code  'Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)' here command is "-skype -callto userid"

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that Skype needs an X server to run properly. So you could enable `X11` forwarding.

X11 forwarding needs to be configured on the client and server side:

On the server side enable X11 forwarding by setting `X11Forwarding yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restarting the ssh service `service sshd restart`. You might also need to install `xauth` on the server side.

On the client side you need to open the ssh connection with the `-X` parameter to enable X11 forwarding for the session.